# Pandas: Nested merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have three dataframes that I need to merge together. Basically, I have one dataframe `df1` that gives me employment for specific sectoral definition (`sector`) and year. Then, I have a second dataframe `df2`that gives me a characteristic  `foo` for each sector and year, but here the sectoral variable is `sector2`.

Finally, I have a dataframe that matches `sector` to `sector2`. This is a n:1 relation: a single `sector2` can be matched to several `sector`.

As these dataframes are pretty large, I'm looking for the most efficient way to merge these dataframes over year and sector, while respecting the sector-sector2 links. I do not need rows where either `establishments` or `foo` is empty.

My standard way of merging already broke because of the n:1 matching - I got

```
NotImplementedError: Index._join_level on non-unique index is not implemented
```

How should I attack this problem?

Here are my dataframe samples:

- df1

  ```
               establishments  employment
  year sector                             
  2005  22111               5        1853
        22112               7          70
        44511               4         264
        45211               4         637
        45299               4          80
  ```
- df2

  ```
                    foo
  Year sector2       
  2005 1111A0     19973
  2005 1111A0     17241
  2005 1111A0     13259
  2005 1111A0     13646
  2005 1111A0     13721
  ```
- my bridge

  ```
                  description  sector
  sector2                        
   1111A0     Oilseed farming   11111
   1111A0     Oilseed farming   11112
   1111B0       Grain farming   11113
   1111B0       Grain farming   11114
   1111B0       Grain farming   11115
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You should make an `reset_index` on each dataframe and then merge them.
After the `reset_index` you will have unique indexes and be able to execute the merging.

Comment: But wouldnt that merge along the (new integer) index? How does that respect my sector, sector2 bridge?

Comment: All right, let say you want to merge `df2` with `my bridge`. A single `sector2` can be matched to several `sector`. But what about `foo` and `year`? How can we and pandas decide to which `sector` belong to which `foo`?